# Easy Custom Labeling plugin - Cannot find leader lines/arrow button

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, labeling

I have installed the Easy Custom Labeling plugin but the toolbar is nowhere to be found. I have checked the box "Activate experimental plugins" in the Plugins' "Settings" menu. Does anyone know what I might have forgotten? I am using QGIS 2.6.

EDIT: I am able to see the "Easy" label button. However I am not able to see the other functions that I have seen in other posts where Easy Custom Labeling is mentioned, such as "Generate line", the "Arrow button", etc.

Perhaps I should have mentioned that what I am trying to achieve is create leader lines (possibly with arrows) between labels and polygons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted the plugin developer, and everything's much clearer now. I thought I would share what I learned, hoping it could be useful to someone else.

Once you have generated a new layer in **Plugins -> Easy Custom Labeling -> Generates a layer...**, leader lines should appear automatically when you use the **Move label** button in the **Label** toolbar, as shown in the plugin's [official video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Vc9A8CxfAA&feature=youtu.be). However, that did not work for me. What I did to go around this was:

- open the **Properties** dialog for the newly-generated layer
- click on **Style**
- click on **Data defined properties...** (by clicking on the second level in the **Symbol layers** dialog)

I noticed that the **Color** box was checked, and that the following code was there:

> CASE WHEN LblShowCO = 0 OR $length < 1 THEN '255,255,255,0' WHEN NOT LblShowCO THEN '0,0,0,150' END

By unchecking this box I was able to see the leader lines for the (pinned) labels that I had moved around. I then played around with the **Symbol layers** dialog to add an arrowhead to the line.

Comment: If anyone comes across this now, the dialog box in QGis may have changed. But switching the line type to 'Generate Geometry', clicking Apply, then switching back to Simple Line, worked.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this in QGIS3.4 and the solution I found to work was adding the following expression to the Geometry Generator.

```
make_line( make_point(  "LblX" , "LblY"  ) , centroid($geometry ))
```